# Null pointer exception in eclipselink-2.7.14

Tags: eclipselink, java-17

I am using Jdk 17 with eclipselink-2.7.14.
I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ClassConstants.<clinit>(ClassConstants.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.AbstractIdentityMap.getDefaultIdentityMapClass(AbstractIdentityMap.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.<init>(Project.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.<init>(Project.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.<init>(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.broker.SessionBroker.<init>(SessionBroker.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.JavaSEPlatform.atLeast(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.JavaSEPlatform)" because "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.JavaSEPlatform.CURRENT" is null
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.getProvider(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.<clinit>(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:45)
```

While creating the  new instance of SessionBroker broker = new SessionBroker(); I am getting NPE

Comment: Please check this guildeline on how to ask questions here. That way people will be able to help you better and quickly:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest version (4.x) for JDK 17 support : https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/releases/4.0.php